# \labelcrefformat vs. \creflabelformat

Tags: cleveref

What do the two commands `\labelcrefformat` and `\creflabelformat` do exactly?  In the documentation of cleveref I see both mentioned.  While `\creflabelformat` is described (without any examples, unfortunately) on p. 15, `\labelcrefformat` is mentioned only twice (without any particularities):

> The `\labelcref` command will typeset cross-reference labels using the default label format if no type-specific format is defined using `\creflabelformat` (see Sections 8.1.1 and 8.1.2). Note that, if you customise reference formats using the low-level commands, you may want to also explicitly define the `\labelcref` formats to match, using the `\labelcrefformat` etc. commands (see Section 8.2).

The only other reference to `\labelcrefformat` is in Section 8.2:

> If you define the format for a particular cross-reference type using the low-level customisation commands, and still want to use the `\labelcref` command to produce just the label part of the cross-reference, then you must also define the appropriate `\labelcref` formats for that type. This is done using the `\labelcrefformat`, `\labelcrefrangeformat`, `\labelcrefmultiformat` and `\labelcrefrangemultiformat` commands.

So how do these two commands differ? Any examples of using these two commands, especially `\labelcrefformat`?

Answer (score 1):

`creflabelformat` is a "high-level" setting in cleveref terminology.

It allows you to change how the reference *itself* (without the type) will be rendered for a specific reference type.

Basically it does exactly the same as `crefdefaultlabelformat`, but for rendering references of a particular type instead of all references altogether <sub><sub>(except equations, because reasons).</sub></sub>

Example:

```
\creflabelformat{section}{(((#2#1#3)))}
...
See \cref{mylabel}. % mylabel points to a section 2.1
```

produces `See sect. (((2.1)))`, but references to all other types (figures, tables etc.) will be untouched. On the other hand, section numbers will look like (((X.X))) for all rendering modes, including ranges (like `sect. (((2.2)))-(((2.4)))`) and lists (like `sect. (((2.2))), (((2.4))) and (((2.6)))`).

---

`labelcrefformat` is a "low-level" setting in cleveref terminology.

Together with `labelcrefrangeformat`, `labelcrefmultiformat` and `labelcrefrangemultiformat` it allows you to completely redefine the behavior of `\labelcref`, exactly as `crefformat`, `crefrangeformat`, `crefmultiformat` and `crefrangemultiformat` allow you to completely redefine the behavior of `\cref`.

Example:

```
\crefformat{section}{sect.~<#2#1#3>}
\labelcrefformat{section}{<#2#1#3>}
...
\labelcref{mylabel} % mylabel points to a section 2.1
```

produces `<2.1>`.

Notice that `labelcrefformat` and friends are meant to be crutches to make `\labelcref` work when you tune the behavior of `\cref` with `crefformat` (and friends), i.e. use the low-level interface. If you *also* use `\creflabelformat` (i.e. high-level interface), *and* remove `\crefformat` from the example above, `\labelcref` will be rendered as usual. (Obviously this is not a problem since it's a degenerate case).